# How to get ord (unicode) of each character in string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a function to take a string and print each character in the string in unicode separated by a space. This is all I was able to get:

```
def get_ords(s):
    """
    >>> get_ords('abc')
    '97 98 99 '
    >>> get_ords('a b c')
    '97 32 98 32 99 '
    """
    for ch in s:
        return ord(ch)
```

This gives me the output:

```
Expected:
    '97 98 99 '
Got:
    97

Expected:
    '97 32 98 32 99 '
Got:
    97
```

I can't figure out how to get each one? I thought of using `str.split()` but I didn't think that would work properly.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` exits the function, so you should create a list and keep appending to it:

```
def get_ords(s):
    """
    >>> get_ords('abc')
    '97 98 99 '
    >>> get_ords('a b c')
    '97 32 98 32 99 '
    """
    l = []
    for ch in s:
        l.append(str(ord(ch)))
    return ' '.join(l)
```

Even better:

```
def get_ords(s):
    """
    >>> get_ords('abc')
    '97 98 99 '
    >>> get_ords('a b c')
    '97 32 98 32 99 '
    """
    return ' '.join([str(ord(ch)) for ch in s])
```

Or without calling, `print`ing, and assuming python 3 (just add a `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the file in python 2):

```
def get_ords(s):
    """
    >>> get_ords('abc')
    '97 98 99 '
    >>> get_ords('a b c')
    '97 32 98 32 99 '
    """
    for ch in s:
        print(ord(ch), end=' ')
    print()
```

And assuming python 3 again (do the same as above if python 2,  `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the file):

```
def get_ords(s):
    """
    >>> get_ords('abc')
    '97 98 99 '
    >>> get_ords('a b c')
    '97 32 98 32 99 '
    """
    [print(ord(ch), end=' ') for ch in s]
```

And now in the first two cases:

```
print(get_ords('abc'))
```

Output:

```
97 98 99
```

And now in the last two cases:

```
get_ords('abc')
```

Output:

```
97 98 99
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I just haven't learnt about appending and joining as of yet in my class, so wasn't sure of how to do this.

Comment: @puppyonkik Remember to accept and up-vote if it works :-)

Comment: Could also print(" ".join(str(ord(ch)) for ch in s))

Comment: @U9-Forward sorry to be a nuisance, one more thing.. how do I get the output to be wrapped in singular quotations so my doctest passes? my professor is stingy about that. (eg the output is '97 98 99')

Comment: @puppyonkik check the first two examples, they do it.

Answer (score 2):

`return` is only called once in a function.

You can either

1. Create a local variable that stores all of your output, like so:

```
def get_ords(s):
    """
    >>> get_ords('abc')
    '97 98 99 '
    >>> get_ords('a b c')
    '97 32 98 32 99 '
    """
    ret = []
    for ch in s:  
        ret.append(ord(ch))
    return ' '.join(ret)  # or skip the for loop using a list comprehension here
```

2. Use yield to define a generator

```
def get_ords(s):
    """
    >>> get_ords('abc')
    '97 98 99 '
    >>> get_ords('a b c')
    '97 32 98 32 99 '
    """
    yield ord(ch)

x = get_ords(s)

for y in x:
    print(y)
```

Comment: Alec, little slower than me... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Good time to learn comprehensions. They are both shorter to write and often more efficient that iteratively growing an array:

```
def get_ords(s):
    """
    >>> get_ords('abc')
    '97 98 99 '
    >>> get_ords('a b c')
    '97 32 98 32 99 '
    """
    return ' '.[ord(c) for s in c]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
def get_ords(s):
    return ' '.join([str(ord(ch)) for ch in s])
```

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed you might use list-comprehension for that. As already noted only one `return` in every function run is executed, so if you wish to fire return more than once you need to arrange your function in recursive manner that is:

```
def get_ords(s):
    if len(s)>=2:
        return f"{ord(s[0])} "+get_ords(s[1:])
    else:
        return f"{ord(s[0])}"
print(get_ords('abc')) # 97 98 99
print(get_ords('a b c')) # 97 32 98 32 99
```

Above code uses so-called f-strings ([tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)) available in Python 3.6 onwards. Naturally this is much less readable than list-comprehension method, however in some use cases recursion is useful.